# Sort lines in a string, group data

Tags: python

I'm trying to group string like a map output.

Ex:

```
String = "
    a,a
    a,b
    a,c
    b,a
    b,b
    b,c"
```

Op:

```
a a,b,c
b a,b,c
```

Is this kind of output possible in a single step??

Answer (score 5):

use the builtin `sorted`:

```
In [863]: st=sorted(String.split())
Out[863]: ['aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb']
```

to print it:

```
In [865]: print '\n'.join(st)
aa
ab
ba
bb
```

`list.sort` sorts the list in place and returns `None`, that's why when you `print(lines.sort())` it shows nothing! show your list by `lines.sort(); prnit(lines)` ;)

Comment: What python shell are you using?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart ipython-qtconsole

Answer (score 3):

Note that [`list.sort()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) sorts the list in-place, and does *not* return a new list. That's why

```
print(lines.sort())
```

is printing `None`. Try:

```
lines.sort()    # This modifies lines to become a sorted version
print(lines)
```

Alternatively, there is the built-in [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function, which returns a sorted copy of the list, leaving the original unmodified. Use it like this:

```
print(sorted(list))
```

Answer (score 1):

Because so far the other answers focus on sorting, I want to contribute this for the grouping issue:

```
String = """
    a a
    a b
    a c
    b a
    b b
    b c"""

pairs = sorted(line.split() for line in String.split('\n') if line.strip() )

from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby
for first, grouper in groupby(pairs, itemgetter(0)):
    print first, "\t", ', '.join(second for first, second in grouper)

Out:
a   a, b, c
b   a, b, c
```

Comment: How do I do if the separator is Comma instead of space?

Comment: @user1919035 `line.split(',')` instead of `line.split()`. Maybe you have to remove the whitespace around the letters: `map(str.strip, line.split(','))`

Comment: I didn't get where to implement map(str.strip, line.split(','))

Comment: @user1919035 instead of `line.split()`