# Remove duplicate lines from a string

Tags: python

I'm not much familiar with Python. But, I want to remove duplicates from lines of a string.

Ex:

```
str = "aaa
       aaa
       aaa
       abb
       abb
       ccc"
```

List is a sorted ordered list.

```
str = "aaa
       abb
       ccc"
```

I've millions of such lines. I know the long way of removing duplicates, but would like to know if any possible short form.

Comment: Have you heard of `set` and `split`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't use `str` as a variable name, since it's a builtin type
2. use `'''...'''` to wrap multi-line strings
3. use `sorted`, `set`, `split` in your case,

e.g.:

```
In [895]: print '\n'.join(sorted(set(ss.split())))
aaa
abb
ccc
```

thank @user2357112 for mentioning, if you want to preserve the order the words apear, use `OrderedDict`:

```
In [910]: ss = '''zzz #<----------
     ...:        aaa
     ...:        aaa
     ...:        aaa
     ...:        abb
     ...:        abb
     ...:        ccc'''

In [911]: from collections import OrderedDict
     ...: print '\n'.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(ss.split()))
zzz #here zzz ranks the first
aaa
abb
ccc
```

Comment: Or if order matters, `'\n'.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(ss.split()))`.

Answer (score 1):

If the list is sorted, you don't need a set, because all the duplicates will be grouped together.  Just track the last element

```
prevLine = NIL
for line in lines
  if line != prevLine:
    # output line
  prevLine = line
```

(My python is rusty, don't trust the syntax here.  I'll check it)

Answer (score 1):

try set:

```
init_str = """aaa
       aaa
       aaa
       abb
       abb
       ccc"""

final_string=""
for x in set(init_str.split()):
    final_string+=x+'\n'
print final_string
```

Answer (score 1):

well, basically here's what you want:

```
"\n".join(set(s.split('\n')))
```

though, your string is not a valid python string, so you may want to do this instead:

```
s = """aaa
       aaa
       aaa
       abb
       abb
       ccc"""
```

but then you might want to get rid of the trailing spaces:

```
"\n".join(set([s.strip() for s in s.split('\n')]))
```

N.B.: as @zhangxaochen suggests, it's indeed a bad idea to use a python reserved word as a variable name. Use something like `s` instead.

N.B.2: using sorted and set makes sense as it looks like you're processing the same dataset from your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963150/sort-lines-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Since your data is already sorted, we can take advantage of the existing order to beat the performance of a solution based on `set` or `OrderedDict`. Using [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools
lines = [key for key, group in itertools.groupby(s.split())]
```

This avoids building up a big set of lines unnecessarily. If the data is coming from a file, a small adaptation will beat the memory consumption of all set- or OrderedDict-based solutions by orders of magnitude:

```
with open('lines.txt') as f:
    for line, group in itertools.groupby(f):
        print line,
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you are dealing with sorted input but in the event input is not sorted and you need input order to be retained, you could use `OrderedDict`

```
from collections import OrderDict
s = r'''aaa
aaa
aaa
abb
abb
ccc'''
for line in OrderedDict.fromkeys(s.splitlines()):
  print line
aaa
abb
ccc
```